# Traduzir mensagem de erro

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho a seguinte classe Request chamada ModelRequest com as seguintes funções

```
...
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:customers',
            'first_name' => 'required|string|max:100',               
            
        ];
    }

public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'email.unique' => trans('validation.custom.unique', ['attribute' => 'endereço de e-mail']),
            'first_name.required' => trans('validation.required', ['attribute' => 'Primeiro nome']),
        ];

    }
```

Que me retorna o seguinte:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "O endereço de e-mail já está sendo utilizado"
        ],
        "first_name": [
            "O primeiro nome é obrigatório"
        ]
    }
}
```

Note que os erros estão traduzidos

Como eu poderia mudar o texto do erro inicial de `messages`?

```
{
    "message": "Minha mensagem personalida",
    ...
```

Comment: Na doc do Laravel tem um bom exemplo https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: Eu gostaria de mudar o texto de `message`, desses outros já está sendo feito

Comment: Não tem como fazer personalizando erros validação. Intercepte o erro de validação dentro do método [render()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#renderable-exceptions) do manipulador de exceções e renderize uma exceção personalizada.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui https://stackoverflow.com/a/59738977/4623423 ou a dica do Augusto pode ser uma solução

Comment: Deu certo! Value pela sugestão.. Se quiser adicionar a resposta, Fique à vontade! Mesmo assim, muito obrigado!

Answer (score -3):

Crie o arquivo "pt-br.json" na pasta lang e dentro do arquivo cole o seguinte código.

```
{
  "The given data was invalid.": "Minha mensagem personalida"
}
```

Caso você tenha configurado no arquivo "config/app.php" a chave "locale" como "pt", por exemplo, basta criar o arquivo "pt.json" na pasta lang.

Além disso, você pode traduzir para qualquer outra língua, porém, será necessário alterar a língua atual em tempo de execução.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).